# How to check if a day in a timetable is full or not in SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm finishing a small web app that allows a group of people to reserve rooms for meetings and other activities. So, I have a monthly report with the days of the chosen month. After selecting a day, It will show the scheduled timetable for the day and for that room.
The days are color coded whether they have no reservations made are partially full or are completely full.

On the SQL Server side I have a table to register the reservations made in which I have fields for the role, day (date), start time and end time of the meeting (both datetime).

So my question is: is there a way to know, with querying, if a day is completely full or not? I want to have some kind of left join or CTE to put a flag in the select statement telling me if the day is full or not.

EDIT: I was asked for the table structure so I'm putting it here to help other people who might run into the same kind of question.

Table "reservations":

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
id_type_event INT,
reservation_date DATE,
start_time TIME(5),
end_time TIME(5),
id_reservation_state INT,
date_created DATETIME,
id_user_created INT
```

Question 2: should I change the "start_time" and "end_time" to DATETIME?

Comment: Quick answer: yes but full answer depends on your tables. Publish DDL statement for your tables.

Comment: One easy way I can think of is summing the deltas of each reservation (end time - start time) for a given day, and if the number of seconds is equal to the bookable number of seconds, then it's full. This can be fragile depending on how complicated your system is though.

Comment: @Ownaginatious Yes, I think that is exactly the simplest approach and best for my case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a date table then you could so something simple like this;

```
DECLARE @QueryDate date; SET @QueryDate = '2016-05-31'

SELECT
dt.BookingDate
,bkd.Room
,CASE 
    WHEN bkd.HoursBooked < 8
        THEN 'Not Full'
    WHEN bkd.HoursBooked > 10
        THEN 'Over Booked'
    ELSE 'Fully Booked'
END BookingStatus
FROM
DateTable dt
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
        Room
        ,BookingDate
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(mi,StartTimeDate,EndTimeDate)) HoursBooked
        FROM RoomBookings
        GROUP BY
        Room
        ,BookingDate
    ) bkd
ON dt.Room = bkd.Room
AND dt.BookingDate = bkd.BookingDate
WHERE dt.BookingDate = @QueryDate
```

I'm working with limited information in your post, but if you have two tables, one being the date table the other being the bookings table then this will give you what you're after.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I think this is the best and simplest approach for my case scenario. Thank you!
I'll edit my question so it's more useful for others too.

Comment: Yeah, it's going to be one of the simplest and most reliable. Feel free to upvote and mark as accepted if it answers your question.